# Linux VM/nodejs Issue: Nodemon, Coffee, etc Not Executing

Tags: linux, node.js, coffeescript, virtualbox, nodemon

I'm having issues installing and running programs with npm. I am running Ubuntu inside virtualbox on my windows 7 PC.

Npm is installing node_modules just fine in the sense that Nodejs can require and use them; However, executables such as nodemon and coffee are not working.

ex:

```
zach@zach-VirtualBox:~$ sudo npm install -g coffee-script
/usr/bin/coffee -> /usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee
/usr/bin/cake -> /usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/cake
coffee-script@1.7.1 /usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script
└── mkdirp@0.3.5
zach@zach-VirtualBox:~$ coffee -v
zach@zach-VirtualBox:~$
```

it doesn't give a "command doesn't exist" so it sees that coffee has been set, but none of the commands work. Anybody know how to rectify this?

Comment: I figured it out, for anyone having the same issue you may have installed "node" (which is not equivalent to nodejs ;) as well. using: "sudo apt-get remove node" resolved my issue.

Comment: _"for anyone having the same issue..."_ Please, for future reference, post that as a self approved _answer_.

Comment: @ZachDahl You should post it as answer.

Comment: I forget what stackoverflow will allow me to do since I don't have any rep (mostly a lurker :P). I've added this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, for anyone having the same issue you may have installed "node" (which is not equivalent to nodejs ;) as well. using: "sudo apt-get remove node" resolved my issue.